# int(), can't convert non-string with explicit base in python

Tags: python

there are two things I can't understand:

1-What does "**non-string - with explicit base**" means? is it like pointers?
2 How to solve it?

you can check the code and the error it appears on line 25 [here](https://www.online-python.com/gq6Noj7E1H). (it is clickable)

Error message:

```
dec_list.append(int(rmsg[x],2)) 
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

It's obvious I'm not a python guy but I'm trying to do smth from time to time.

my aaaa.txt file contains
`01110001010100010101010001010101011001010110110101010101010101000001010110010101010000010101001001010010110101`

```
    local_file=open('aaaa.txt' , 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') 
    #1st checkpoint open and read the file
        a=local_file.read()
    n=10
    i=0
    msg=list() #create a blank list for lsb first
    rmsg=list() #create a blank list for msb first
    asciimsg=list() #create a blank list for decoded ASCII character
    def swap(num):
        str_num = str(num)
   

 str_swapped = str_num[-1] +str_num[-2] + str_num[2:-2]  + str_num[1] + str_num[0]
    return int(str_swapped)


    while (n<=len(a)):
# 3th cp: gets the 7 bit, lsb first in the aaaa.txt, one by one till the end
        msg.append(a[i+1:n-2])  
        rmsg.append(swap(a[i+1:n-2]))
        n=n+10
        i=i+10
    print('lsb first binary:')
    print(msg)
    print('msb first binary(ASCII):')
    print(rmsg)
    dec_list=list()
    for x in range(len(rmsg)):
       dec_list.append(int(rmsg[x],2)) #4th checkpoint: convert to decimal
    print('ASCII in decimal:')
    print(dec_list)
    for z in dec_list:
        asciimsg.append(chr(z)) #5th cp: use the chr function to convert to ascii
    print(asciimsg)
    shortmsg=""
    for t in asciimsg:
        shortmsg=shortmsg+t
    print(shortmsg) #6th cp: printing the decoded msg
```

Comment: If you give a base, you must also pass your number as its textual representation in this base. But apparently, what you passed wasn't even a string, hence the error. If you don't give a base, the first argument can be something else, like a float for example;

Comment: never mind I just wrote something else. thank you a lot

Comment: Well, sorry, but you probably didn't. What I mean is that `rmsg[x]` should have been a string, representing a valid base 2 number. And it certainly isn't. Just try to `print(rmsg[x])` before trying to convert it and see what it is. And just putting a `str(...)` around it won't solve the problem...

Comment: If you're converting to another base (which you are), then the first argument must be a string (which it isn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is not a `str`, so convert it to a string first:

```
dec_list.append(int(str(rmsg[x]), 2))
```

It is much more Pythonic to use a list comprehension instead of a for-loop like that, though:

```
dec_list = [int(str(c), 2) for c in rmsg]
```

Comment: They linked the code in the question (look for the word "here"), so it was clear that it was in fact integers like that.

Answer (score 0):

int() is a method used in python to convert numbers in the form of strings to integers, for example: "2" is a string, int("2") = 2 so now 2 is an integer, same for your case but the base case is that the initial form of the message is neither an integer nor a string so first you need to convert the message to a string using str(message) and then int(message), also put as int(str(message)).

Comment: so basically when I write int() or str() it's similar to downcasting in java if you have any knowledge in Java. Thank you

Comment: basically yes it is similar to downcasting, no problem!